# Loading iframe before launching .ready();

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, facebook-comments, coda-slider

I have a Facebook comments iframe in the last slide of a carousel. The carousel uses autoHeight to figure out the height of the elements apply it to the slide.

The problem is the comments iframe is loading after the script calculates the height.

How can I load the iframe before the script loads the carousel?

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

> Loading iframe before launching .ready();

Try utilizing [`$.holdReady()`](http://apjquery.com/jquery.holdReady)

```
$.holdReady(true);
// load `iframe`
$("<iframe>").on("load", function() {
  $.holdReady(false)
});

$(function() {
  // do stuff when `iframe` loaded
  // calculate `height`
});
```